# 0MQ: on passing a context to a pool of threads a Segmentation fault was thrown

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am building a small program ([here](https://pastebin.com/ysqbxXzB)), in which the `main()` sends the same `msg` to all worker threads and the worker threads simply print the `msg`.

I think I have exactly followed [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:mtserver) tutorial, from the official guide.

I pass the 0MQ `context` to thread via a void pointer and then cast it back to `zmq::context_t *`. But still I got the Segmentation fault. Below is info from coredump in GDB:

```
Core was generated by `./test 1'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  zmq::ctx_t::check_tag (this=this@entry=0xabadcafe) at src/ctx.cpp:89
89  src/ctx.cpp: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fcdaae3f700 (LWP 1428))]
(gdb) bt
#0  zmq::ctx_t::check_tag (this=this@entry=0xabadcafe) at src/ctx.cpp:89
#1  0x00007fcdad17c275 in zmq_socket (ctx_=0xabadcafe, type_=7) at src/zmq.cpp:245
#2  0x0000000000402da1 in zmq::socket_t::init (this=0x7fcdaae3edf0, context_=..., type_=7) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:649
#3  0x0000000000402ac3 in zmq::socket_t::socket_t (this=0x7fcdaae3edf0, context_=..., type_=7) at /usr/include/zmq.hpp:463
#4  0x0000000000401f18 in task1 (arg=0x170ac20) at test.cpp:21
#5  0x00000000004050fe in std::_Bind_simple<void (*(void*))(void*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (this=0x170e0d8)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1531
#6  0x0000000000405008 in std::_Bind_simple<void (*(void*))(void*)>::operator()() (this=0x170e0d8) at /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1520
#7  0x0000000000404f98 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*(void*))(void*)> >::_M_run() (this=0x170e0c0) at /usr/include/c++/5/thread:115
#8  0x00007fcdacc48c80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007fcdacf196ba in start_thread (arg=0x7fcdaae3f700) at pthread_create.c:333
#10 0x00007fcdac6b782d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
(gdb) quit
```

Program compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lzmq -lpthread -g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pool.push_back(thread(task1, (void *)context));
```

Should be

```
pool.push_back(thread(task1, (void *)&context));
```

As you want to pass the address of `context`

Answer (score 1):

### In this use-case, a Thread-less `Context()` can help:

Native API recommends this practice for pure-**`inproc://`** transport-class based multi-threaded usage:

> The **`zmq_init()`** function initialises a ØMQ context.
>
> The `io_threads` argument specifies the size of the ØMQ thread pool to handle I/O operations. If your application is using only the inproc transport for messaging you may set this to zero, otherwise set it to at least one.
>
> **Thread safety**
>
> A ØMQ context is thread safe and may be shared among as many application threads as necessary, without any additional locking required on the part of the caller.
>
> This function is deprecated by zmq_ctx_new(3).

More recent { API / c++ wrapper } moves this step ( originally available in a { v2.1.11 API / c++ wrapper } via `Context( NUM_io_threads )` right upon an instantiation ) into a { v4.2.2 } split process in a post-instatiation ( but pre-socket association ) state via a setup call
**`zmq_ctx_set( *ctx, ZMQ_IO_THREADS, 0 )`**

---

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{   
    int worker_num;
    if (  argc != 2 ) { cout << "1 parameter pls" << endl;                           exit(1); } // EXIT[1]
    try
    {
      if ( !has_only_digits( string( argv[1] ) ) ) { cout << "digit pls" << endl;    exit(1); } // EXIT[2]
      worker_num =     stoi( string( argv[1] ) );
    }
    catch ( exception e ) { cout << "exception while processing parameters" << endl; exit(1); } // EXIT[3]
 // _______________________________________  // ZeroMQ inproc use-case W/O IO-thread
    zmq::context_t context( 0 );             // 
 // _______________________________________  // 

    zmq::socket_t  distask_socket( context, ZMQ_PUSH );
                   distask_socket.bind( "inproc://task_publisher" );

    vector<thread> pool;

    for ( int i = 0; i < worker_num; i++ )
    {
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      pool.push_back( thread(           task1,
                              (void *) &context
                              )
                      );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < worker_num; i++ )
    {
      zmq::message_t msg( 6 );
      memcpy( (void *) msg.data(), "World", 6 ); 
      distask_socket.send( msg );
    }

    for ( auto &t : pool )
      t.join();

    exit(0);
}
```

---

Worth in case squeezing the last bits of performance & shaving off latency sources.